# Go code is much slower than c++ code with the same routine

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, go

I am solving [the algorithm problems from the Korean site](https://algospot.com/judge/problem/read/FENCE).

The problem description is simple. Find the largest consecutive rectangle area from given stick sequences. Sequences can't be swapped and the width of a stick is 1.
Max number of sticks is 20,000. Max height of a stick is 10,000.

I first solve the problem with `cpp` and it took only a hundred millis. And then, I port it to `go` code because I am studying `go` right now. Unfortunately, it exceeded the time limit (over 3 seconds).

I'm sure I wrote the same algorithm with both languages, and I know the `slicing` in go does not take much time because it only copies the start address of the memory.
What is the main problem with `go`?

## CPP code

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int solve(vector<int> &v, int begin, int end);
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    scanf("%d", &c);

    while (c--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        vector<int> v;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            int temp;
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            v.push_back(temp);
        }
        printf("%d\n", solve(v, 0, v.size()));
    }
}
int findMidMax(vector<int> &v, int begin, int end);

int solve(vector<int> &v, int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin == end)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (begin + 1 == end)
    {
        return v[begin];
    }

    int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    int leftMax = solve(v, begin, mid);
    int rightMax = solve(v, mid, end);
    int midMax = findMidMax(v, begin, end);

    return max(leftMax, max(rightMax, midMax));
}

int findMidMax(vector<int> &v, int begin, int end)
{
    int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    int left = mid - 1;
    int right = mid;
    int minHeight = min(v[left], v[right]);
    int size = 2 * minHeight;
    while (begin < left || right + 1 < end)
    {
        if (begin < left && (right + 1 == end || v[left - 1] > v[right + 1]))
        {
            --left;
            minHeight = min(minHeight, v[left]);
        }
        else
        {
            ++right;
            minHeight = min(minHeight, v[right]);
        }
        size = max(size, minHeight * (right - left + 1));
    }
    return size;
}
```

## Go code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var c int
    fmt.Scan(&c)

    for ; c > 0; c-- {
        var n int
        fmt.Scan(&n)
        arr := make([]int, n)
        for idx := range arr {
            fmt.Scan(&arr[idx])
        }
        fmt.Println(solve(arr))
    }
}

func solve(arr []int) int {
    if len(arr) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    if len(arr) == 1 {
        return arr[0]
    }
    mid := len(arr) / 2
    leftMax := solve(arr[:mid])
    rightMax := solve(arr[mid:])
    midMax := findMidMax(arr)

    return max(leftMax, max(rightMax, midMax))
}

func findMidMax(arr []int) int {
    mid := len(arr) / 2
    left, right := mid-1, mid
    minHeight := min(arr[left], arr[right])
    ret := minHeight * 2
    for left > 0 || right+1 < len(arr) {
        if left > 0 && (right+1 == len(arr) || arr[left-1] > arr[right+1]) {
            left--
            minHeight = min(minHeight, arr[left])
        } else {
            right++
            minHeight = min(minHeight, arr[right])
        }
        ret = max(ret, minHeight*(right-left+1))
    }
    return ret
}

func min(a int, b int) int {
    if a > b {
        return b
    }
    return a
}
func max(a int, b int) int {
    if a < b {
        return b
    }
    return a
}
```

Comment: I do not know much about Go, but AFAIK isn't `arr[:mid]` copied when functions are called because arguments are passed *by value*? See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-arguments-in-golang/

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Thanks for your comment. I suspect that problem first, too. But after I carefully read Go doc, I found that it can't be an issue. 
`arr[:mid]` is called `slice` in Go. And if I understand Go properly, passing the `slice` to a function only takes its memory pointer, length, and slice capacity. So the total bytes passed are only 24 bytes for each recursion.

Comment: Are you sure that the Go solution is correct by testing it on some smaller input? I'm asking because the root cause could be some off by one error in binary search or similar that results in an infinite loop. Just to make sure before you go investigating more complicated matter.

Comment: Does Go have reference or copy semantics ? Passing `vector<int> &v` is lightweight. Is passing `arr []int` also lightweight in Go ?

Comment: *And then, I port it to go code* -- Maybe the mistake is that you do not know the destination language (in this case, Go) well enough to make such a port successful.  Line-by-line translations from language A to language B are rarely any good.  The way a successful port is done is to understand what language A is doing, and then in language B, implement the same thing by throwing language A away.  Do not use language A as a model in implementing the solution in language B.

Comment: Yes, it is @Jeffrey slices are small structs that point to the underlying data store.

Comment: @user1984 Yes, Go solution is correct. And also it passed the test if the time limit is 10 secs. But I should look into my algorithm more carefully. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Thank you. How big is the performance difference? What are the timings? This difference in parameter size may explain the performance difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is my first time porting code to other language line by line. And I totally agree with your advice. Thanks!

Comment: @JérômeRichard The performance difference is more than 30 times. But `Go`'s arguments size is only 3 times more than `cpp`.

Comment: @wurikiji -- Yes.  If you were to give that same question to a Go programmer who knows nothing about C++, their solution would more than likely look very little like your solution, and would run fast.  That's the difference between doing line-by-line translations, and actually knowing the language and implementing the solution using the language's paradigms.

Comment: I would suggest https://brendanjryan.com/2018/02/28/profiling-go-applications.html as a worthwhile idea to try in tracking down performance.

Comment: Ok, 30 time is a lot, but the GccGo compiler appear to generate an awful program without optimizations enabled (partially due to checks). What compiler did you used? And did you enabled optimization with like `-O3`?

Comment: _What_ time are you measuring? The entry functions of both solutions ask the user for input. What piece of code is being timed, then? What happens if you measure the performance of your Go code using [its standard tooling](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B) while having that user input conveniently prefilled (conained in the program)? You also must not include I/O operations (that is, any code from `fmt`) into what is measured.

Comment: @kostix I used official go test -bench with cpuprofile and memprofile. I used the same process you mentioned; No fmt I/O, but prefilled input. solve() function and findMidMax() were only measured. The results were as expected in terms of ratio of each function. Time complexity is O(n log n) and findMidMax is the most consuming operation. But the absolute time measured is different between Go and Cpp.

Comment: @wurikiji, sorry for me being a bit harsh, but that's handwaving because no one can verify your measurements since they simply had not be presented; hence your question is unanswerable. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Cz4csCrN) is how I'd benchmark this code myself. You can try and see whether it will make any difference in your case. Still, keep in mind, that measuring of C++ perf has to use _comparable_ methodics, and also I do not know whether your code is free from UB which could allow the compiler to silently do crazy fast optimizations, either ;-)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. [Go bench](https://pastebin.com/Cz4csCrN), [C++ bench](https://pastebin.com/txpNEKFc). [Results](https://pastebin.com/tuxX0NgH) are within 25% difference.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for your advice! I am not good at asking something. I will make better question next time. Your comments really helped me.

Comment: @rustyx Thanks for that benchmark results. I will take a look at my environments more and do some compile time optimizations. And the format you posted was really good example for me to do the same thing by myself later.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a difference in how you input and output things in your code.
Printing is a time-expensive operation. When you call `printf` and `scanf` in C it probably optimises the code to batch the output, but printing array through `fmt.Println(array)` in go is way more expensive.

Try to do things one-by-one:

- read the data
- handle the data
- print the data

It have to lead to reducing of  `fmt` calls and the time should be closer to a C++ one.

Also there may be some issues with `fmt.Scanf()` parsing speed. You may increase it by reading the full line like this:

```
rdr := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
vals := make([]*int, n)
fmt.Fscanf(rdr, "*this should be the generated line of n '%d' symbols *", vals...)
```