# Decoding os.File to image.Image takes too long

Tags: image, go, decode

As part of my app I need to get interface image.Image out of os.File and I use image.Decode() function. The procedure takes way too long (~300 ms) and I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it?

Here is my code snippet

```
logger.Info("open saved file for image resizing processing")
//open file of imageLocation - imageType, width, height,
fi, err := os.Open(imageLocation)
logger.Info("file opened")
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("error opening newly saved photo file for image conversion: " + err.Error())
    return nil, resterrors.NewIntenalServerError(resterrors.FILE_ERROR)
}
defer fi.Close()
//convert the os.File to image.Image 

logger.Info("decode file to image start")
im, imageType, err := image.Decode(fi)
logger.Info("decode file to image finish")

if err != nil {
    logger.Error("error decoding os.File to image.Image : " + err.Error())
    return nil, resterrors.NewIntenalServerError(resterrors.FILE_ERROR)
}
```

The result output is as follows

```
{"level":"info","timestamp":"2022-02-07T00:42:56.382+0100","caller":"service/upload_service.go:53","msg":"open saved file for image resizing processing"}
{"level":"info","timestamp":"2022-02-07T00:42:56.382+0100","caller":"service/upload_service.go:56","msg":"file opened"}
{"level":"info","timestamp":"2022-02-07T00:42:56.382+0100","caller":"service/upload_service.go:65","msg":"decode file to image start"}
{"level":"info","timestamp":"2022-02-07T00:42:56.697+0100","caller":"service/upload_service.go:67","msg":"decode file to image finish"}
```

I have Windows 11 installed on my HP 455 G8 with Ryzen 7 5800U

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Decoding an image depends on the image type, image size and disk reading speed. Whether 300ms is slow is relative. Why do you think it's slow? What would you consider "not slow"?

Comment: What happens if you do a very simple thing and add buffering reader by doing `… = image.Decode(bufio.NewReader(fi))`?

Comment: Another thing is that you're not profiling image decoding. You should use https://pkg.go.dev/testing#B and profile _only_ image decoding which should read the data from a precreated memory buffer such as `bytes.Buffer`.

Comment: You can see the comments thread of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383036) as an example: I've proposed a proper Go benchmark and then @rustyx added an equivalently set up benchmark for the code's C++ counterpart.

Comment: @kostix I tried with bytes.Buffer - same result.

Comment: @icza I was looking into ways to optimize the whole thing, decoding takes at least 300 ms, usually it is 600 - 700 ms , though the files are quite big ~ 3,5 Mb with 5400x3600 px resolution. 
Following the decoding to image I do resizing into 3 files and convertion to webp and this all takes the same time (although optimized by goroutines ) as just decoding of one single file

Comment: @AndreyYaroshenko Your image has nearly 20 million pixels, that with 3-byte RGB model has 60 million bytes. Decoding / calculating each those bytes doesn't seem off to me for taking 300ms. And there's definitely a decompression algorithm involved (since your file only "weights" 3.5 MB).

Comment: If you take a "reference" implementation such as `libpng` (I don't know what format you're decoding), does it take drastically less time to decode? I mean, it worth understanding whether the Go's implementation is just slow or your problem is sufficiently hard for today's commonly available resources, as @icza suggests

Comment: @kostix thanks for the advice, I will check it and write back on it